# How to access Azure KeyVault secret value from program.cs in blazor server app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor-server-side

I set up Azure KeyVault to hold an API key as a secret.

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app#configure-the-web-app-to-connect-to-key-vault) tutorial and I can see when I debug that it does work. secretValue does have the value of my API key.

in Program.cs:

```
SecretClientOptions options = new SecretClientOptions()
    {
        Retry =
        {
            Delay= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(16),
            MaxRetries = 5,
            Mode = RetryMode.Exponential
         }
    };
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://whichepisodesapi.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential(),options);

KeyVaultSecret secret = await client.GetSecretAsync("tmdbApiKey");

var secretValue = secret.Value;
```

The above code is straight from the tutorial. But it doesn't cover how to use secretValue elsewhere in project, like in Index.razor.

In the code below, I would want to swap out the tmdbApiKey var (from when I was using user-secrets locally) for the key vault variable secretValue. I tried using Configuration dependency injection like with user-secrets but couldn't get it to work. I get a "cannot use local variable declared in a top-level statement in this context" error message every time I try to use secretValue in index.razor.

Index.razor @code section:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        //this is from when user-secrets was being used locally
        var tmdbApiKey = Configuration["API_key"];

        if (enteredActorName != null)
        {
            var encodedName = Uri.EscapeDataString(enteredActorName);

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
                "http://api.tmdb.org/3/search/person?api_key=" + tmdbApiKey + "&query=" + encodedName);
  
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               ...
            }
          }
      }
```

Comment: Does directly use key string work?